# RPM to invoke browser post installation

Tags: linux, centos, gnome, rpm, gui

I am creating an RPM installer for centos 6.5, After installation i want the RPM to invoke the browser and show the installation report.

This installation report shows the details of how the installation went. Including errors and warnings that occurred while installation, goal is to clearly explain the user how the installation went.

I can easily double-click on the .rpm file and see the installation happening through the centos GNOME. But i don't see the successful installation message on the screen after the installation is done.

Can RPM invoke the browser post its installation ? Does rpm have the control of doing the same when the installation is happening through GUI - GNOME. I have tried several blogs related to linux, rpm but haven't got lucky yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no it can't. There's no guarantee you will have a graphical environment available anywhere to open a browser in - you could be on a system with only a WYSE-60 terminal as console and no network connection.

Moreover, if there are errors in the installation, it should not have completed. That's part of what packaging is designed to take care of. If there are warnings, they can either be printed to STDOUT or (preferrably) logged somewhere like `/var/log/<appname>`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply John, i created my own .rpm file and i am focusing on doing the installation through GUI by double-clicking it. I kept wondering on this that after successful installation why don't i see a successful installation message on the screen instead the installation pop-up that shows the progress bar after installation just disappears.